# How to display code as code with color using python django

Tags: python, html, css, django, colors

Context:
I'm developing a web application using Python Django, and I want to display code snippets in the browser with syntax highlighting. For example, I would like to display the following code with different colors:

```
if True:
    print("Hello World")
```

I want to achieve this effect using Django's built-in functionality or any recommended libraries or techniques.

Question:
How can I display code as code in the browser with syntax highlighting using Python Django? Are there any specific libraries or techniques that I can use to achieve this effect?

Thank you.

Comment: I answered something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74972062/7100120)

Answer (score 0):

im not familiar with django but it some editors you use the accent key `code`

Comment: sorry I don't get you.

Comment: @BaboucarrBadjie if you start your code with an accent `
and then end it with an accent ` in the same line.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some editor that allows to do that, something like [ckeditor](https://pypi.org/project/django-ckeditor-5/) or [quill](https://pypi.org/project/django-quill-editor/)
Or maybe something more minimalist (if you don't need the editor) like [pygments](https://pypi.org/project/Pygments/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).