# how do i Insert code template in django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to show a part of code in webpage like below.
is there a library in django or another solution for doing this?

[image]

Sample websites are:
https://realpython.com/python-ai-neural-network/
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html

[image]

Comment: Do you mean like an image? Or an editor style input?

Comment: I found comprehensive answer in [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74971196/django-create-code-blocks-in-html-templates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ace.c9.io/
If you're asking for an input -
Ace Editor seems to have been the simplest one for me to implement, lots of expandability through adding scripts.

https://blog.logrocket.com/exploring-best-syntax-highlighting-libraries/
If you're asking for displaying code - there is highlight.js, microlight, Bright and many more. (if the link goes down, search_query=`code display library`)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/
If you're asking to display an image - have a look at the django documentation on serving those.

Comment: I edited question and added two website that have similar code box.

Comment: @Darwin I have literally given you the resources to do **YOUR** work. Go do it. Have you even read the answer?

Comment: Yes. of course. i read that. thank you. but I do not  want insert image. Other solutions need to be implemented. I will inform you after implementation

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to display a simple code block I would look at the HTML tags `<code> 'Put code here'</code>` and if there are multiple lines of code wrap it with `<pre><code></code></pre>`. You are also able to modify it with CSS.

I found this here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code

If you wanted to upload that image entirely then it would be a different process.

Hope this helps.